# C# use switch statement with RadioButton

Tags: c#, switch-statement, radio-button

I want to use the switch method to assign a string value to a variable.
I define my variable:
string Destination
//Then I could use if; else if; else if... but it is too heavy.
//I'de like to have:
switch (AnyRadioButton is checked)
Destination = checked radio button

I assume it would look like that:

```
switch (????)
case IrelandRaddioButton.Checked = true
Destination = IrelandRadioButton.Text;
Break;

case FranceRaddioButton.Checked = true
Destination = FranceRadioButton.Text;
Break;

case SpainRaddioButton.Checked = true
Destination = SpainRaddioButton.Text;
Break;
```

And so on...
If you could help me writing the correct code for it I'de like to understand better the switch statement and to avoid creating a huge if, else if...
Thanks a lot

Comment: why `switch`, not `if (IrelandRaddioButton.Checked) {...} else if (FranceRaddioButton.Checked) {...}`?

Comment: I have 6 radio button and my lecturer is pointy on that when there are more than 3 or 4 buttons, if; else if is too heavy. I agree with him and to handle the switch statement better is the outcome of it.

Answer (score 0):

If (as in the example) the code for each option is the *same*, you can put it as

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  // Either declare RadioButtons to check or enumerate them 
  // (enumeration depends on whether you use WinForms, WPF, etc.) 
  var buttons = new RadioButton[] {
    IrelandRaddioButton,
    FranceRaddioButton,
    SpainRaddioButton,           
  };

  Destination = buttons.FirstOrDefault(button => button.Checked)?.Text;
```

**Edit:** In case of *WinForms* you can enumerate all `RadioButton`s with a help of `Controls`. Assuming that all `RadioButton`s of interest are on `myPanel` (put `this` if they are on the form)

```
  var buttons = myPanel
    .Controls()
    .OfType<RadioButton>();
```

Then compute `Destination` as usual; you can even combine these queries into one:

```
  Destination = myPanel
    .Controls()
    .OfType<RadioButton>()
    .FirstOrDefault(button => button.Checked)
   ?.Text;
```

Note, that now you can add / remove `RadioButton`s without any code modification

Comment: Seems great for my issue. I use Winforms and I'de really like to use the switch statement.